# inspect.getargvalues returns keyword only args as args instead of varargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, callstack, keyword-argument, code-inspection

How can it be explained that `inspect.getargvalues` returns keyword only args as args instead of varargs. Is this a bug or a documentation bug? Are keyword only args not keyword args? I don't understand.

> inspect.getargvalues(frame)
>
> Get information about arguments passed into a particular frame. A named tuple ArgInfo(args, varargs, keywords, locals) is returned. args
> is a list of the argument names. varargs and keywords are the names of
> the * and ** arguments or None. locals is the locals dictionary of the
> given frame.

```
import inspect
def fun(x, *, y):
    print (inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe()))
```

Output:

```
fun (10, y=20)
ArgInfo(args=['x', 'y'], varargs=None, keywords=None, locals={'y': 20, 'x': 10})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says: "varargs and keywords are the names of the * and ** arguments". Your function doesn't have any `*` or `**` arguments.

The `*` that appears here:

```
def fun(x, *, y):
```

merely serves as a separator between positional arguments and keyword-only arguments.

This would be an example of a function where `varargs` and `keywords` would be set:

```
def fun(*x, **y):
    print(inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe()))
```

which would produce:

```
>>> fun(10, y=20)
ArgInfo(args=[], varargs='x', keywords='y', locals={'x': (10,), 'y': {'y': 20}})
```

Comment: I understand what you say and therefor i accept the answer. However, it is very confusing to me why `**kwargs` are classified as keyword args but the keyword-only args behind `*` not. It is very straightforword to conclude that `keywords` stand for keyword-args and `inspect` handles them unexpectedly different. How can such inconsistecy be accepted by the community?